# Reusable Form components in react hook form with typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hook-form

I'm trying to get typescript working with fields that can belong to different forms. I'd like the Field to define the fields that are needed in the form, so that it can be reused. I've currently used `Control<any>` to circumvent the issues, but that limits typescript utility. The error that I'm getting is

```
  The types of '_options.resolver' are incompatible between these types.
    Type 'Resolver<IFormAncestor, any> | undefined' is not assignable to type 'Resolver<DepForm, any> | undefined'.
      Type 'Resolver<IFormAncestor, any>' is not assignable to type 'Resolver<DepForm, any>'.

44             <TestField control={control} trigger={trigger} getValues={getValues} />
```

```
  Type 'DepForm' is not assignable to type 'IFormAncestor'.

44             <TestField control={control} trigger={trigger} getValues={getValues} />
```

```
interface IFormAncestor {
    a: string;
    b: string;
    c: string;
}

interface DepForm {
    a: string;
    b: string;
}


export const TestField = (props: {
    control: Control<DepForm>;
    getValues: UseFormGetValues<DepForm>;
    trigger: UseFormTrigger<DepForm>;
}) => {
    props.getValues();
    props.trigger();
    return (
        <Controller
            name="a"
            control={props.control}
            defaultValue={''}
            render={({ field }) => {
                return (
                    <div>{field.value}</div>
                );
            }}
        />
    );
};

function TestingAncestorForm() {
    const { control, trigger, getValues } = useForm<IFormAncestor>({
        mode: 'onBlur',
    });
    return (
        <div>
            <TestField control={control} trigger={trigger} getValues={getValues}/>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Is there a way to get this working? Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Using a generic which *extends* DepForm will do it here. I had to assert the `name` and `defaultValue` values, which shouldn't be a practical problem since you know they should be valid in this context, but you might be able to work around that with a bit more fiddling too.

```
function TestField<T extends DepForm>(props: {
    control: Control<T>;
    getValues: UseFormGetValues<T>;
    trigger: UseFormTrigger<T>;
}) {
    props.getValues();
    props.trigger();
    const name : Path<DepForm> = "a";
    const defaultValue : PathValue<DepForm, Path<DepForm>> = "";
    return (
        <Controller<T>
            name={name as Path<T>}
            control={props.control}
            defaultValue={defaultValue as PathValue<T, Path<T>>}
            render={({ field }) => {
                return (
                    <div>{field.value}</div>
                );
            }}
        />
    );
};
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=38&ssc=1&pln=16&pc=1#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAKjgQwM5wEoFNkGN4BmUEIcARFDvmQNwBQokscA3nAMIQB2MxANgBo4AVVRYAYtBABxLDABqyPgFcsqIaIlSAKlGABzfVihDOPfn2NCACshgALG3fuKVWIcrGSopAL5wiEnJKPBgAWnsICABrMIIpWjoGHmMCPCw4AElvEABBLlw1GGhWOjhylAAuOFReYC59egq4ACNq2r0Gporcdrquul8k+phU9LgAESwwHNLm5D7OxrKKtpr+5aGkgmUCmGBuOG0i8WAsPgATAB5tOCwAD1GuC-QpmakAPgAKMGIwVGqLBW5Vw3F4ED41TM4L4Nw+3XKRgUSlUAJEXiksmRblQcIRcDqhmM1U0OV0BiMUDxgwAlHMKr8IP8AHRI1yor40-GMlmEymc-Ggri1OBcZAgDLVWwOK5vHIfOAAXnIyESzSFIouWDSyj42NUUuc7KwsumOScMrlnwVyrIaoqlBgyigXDgX2BzTgV2hFmMcI9noqYolipYwYyaDg0vscKGgcDQphoZ5qGZif4cfjzS1Or1xtDOeQuv1EfQ0eNNwtMe0Hw+maz5Uoz2Moa+bAIZ0ucF8dMVCqBDfjjudrvdg8HVwuwAAbh8WB3zhdmdOUVhfFcAPRT2cB8dc3eB3z1z0bj4e-e+eh0HZ7A6u461er6fKFWrQHKc+kg7gitjpiFCHyVhwGyq7oP4yqeFoPhXNkUgvkU0DfAO8YgBAWrVAA5NwABCKhQJhAgej2+LDi6boHl625nuOXoPjApyLnA-58KGLH+EBUChpx-igTioZ8aivinpRm7Uee9C+EAA)

Comment: well, it's an improvement but I still can make a typo in the controller name, and default value, there is nothing preventing me from passing an object in defaultValue, instead of the required string. If we are to go this way, I think it's best to just use as and treat all parameters as of type DepForm.

Comment: I'm not sure why the RHF types aren't smart enough to figure out that "a" is valid there. You could declare `const name : Path<DepForm> = "a"` and then use it as `name={name as Path<T>}`, etc, which *should* cover type concerns, since you know that T must descend from DepForm. See edits.

Answer (score 1):

So after Chris'es answer I've come up with the following.

```
interface DependantForm {
    a: string;
    b: string;
}

export const DesiredValueField = <T extends DependantForm>(props: {
    control: Control<T>;
    getValues: UseFormGetValues<T>;
    trigger: UseFormTrigger<T>;
}) => {
    const control = props.control as unknown as Control<DependantForm>;
    const getValues = props.getValues as unknown as UseFormGetValues<DependantForm>;
    const trigger = props.getValues as unknown as UseFormTrigger<DependantForm>;
```